# How to manage error handling for multiple React.js applications with routing on S3, particularly when encountering 403 error upon refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

How to manage error handling for multiple React.js applications with routing hosted on an single S3 bucket and delivered via CloudFront, particularly when encountering a 403 error upon refreshing the page?

For instance, consider the following scenario: there's a login page at "https://domainname/foldername/index.html," and after logging in, users are redirected to the dashboard at "https://domainname/foldername/dashboard." However, when attempting to refresh the page, a 403 access denied error occurs. To address this, I contemplated adding a custom error page in CloudFront. While this solution works perfectly for "application1," it creates issues when attempting to refresh "application2" because the custom error page in CloudFront redirects to "application1."

How to handle refreshing for each react js applications?